# How can I cancel TextField edit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I cancel the text field editing. I want no other editing on the `TextField` when the selection is made. I tried it myself, but I couldn't.

```
struct profile: View {
    @State private var iliskiDurumlari: [String] = ["Evli", "Bekar", "Ayrı", "anan"]
    @State private var iliskiVisible = false
    @State private var iliski = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("İlişki Durumu Seçiniz..", text: $iliski)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(Color(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 112 / 255), lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $iliskiVisible, content: actionSheet)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.iliskiVisible.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Bir İlişki Durumu Seçiniz"),
            message: Text("Aşagıda"),
            buttons: iliskiDurumlari.map { value in
                ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(value), action: {
                    self.iliski = value
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the selection is made"?

Comment: I created an ActionSheet, after the selection is made, I want to click on the textfield only to make a selection on the action sheet. I don't want typing on the keyboard. @Asperi

Comment: Maybe you don't need `TextField` and `Text` is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need user input (show keyboard) for this particular field, you can use `Text` instead:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(iliski) // <- change here
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .padding(5)
            .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .stroke(Color(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 112 / 255), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $iliskiVisible, content: actionSheet)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.iliskiVisible.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

and instead of placeholder add initial value:

```
@State private var iliski = "İlişki Durumu Seçiniz.."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss the keyboard and cancel editing of the textfield when the user taps on the Action Sheet then in SwiftUI you need this code:
`UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)` reference here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield

So your code must be like that:

```
func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
    ActionSheet(
        title: Text("Bir İlişki Durumu Seçiniz"),
        message: Text("Aşagıda"),
        buttons: iliskiDurumlari.map { value in
            ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(value), action: {
                self.iliski = value
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            })
        }
    )
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your text field inside the button and disable the text field interaction.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.iliskiVisible.toggle()
            }, label: {
                TextField("İlişki Durumu Seçiniz..", text: $iliski)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(5)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(Color(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 112 / 255), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)//<- Disable interection
            })
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $iliskiVisible, content: actionSheet)
        }
    }
```